# How do I set different size SVGs same height?

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I use a RestAPI, it's giving me different size SVG. Some images are fit but some images don't fit.
Example: If you look at the border and image, you gonna understand.
[image]

The main problem is that; I don't know all pictures sizes, How can ı set this case? (İf it's given 100% height change the card height and ı don't want this.)

```
<div className="countries__card card">
                <div className="card__flag">
                  <LazyLoad
                    height={windowWidth >= 614 ? "210px" : '173px"'}
                    once
                  >
                    <img
                      width={windowWidth >= 614 ? "320px" : "100%"}
                      height={windowWidth >= 614 ? "210px" : '100%"'}
                      src="https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg"
                      alt="flag"
                    />
                  </LazyLoad>
                </div>
                <div className="card__body">
                  <div className="card__body-name">
                    <h5>Lorem</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card__body-infos">
                    <span className="country-capital">Capital: Lorem</span>
                    <span className="country-currencies">Currency: Lorem</span>
                    <span className="country-region">Region: Lorem</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <footer className="card__footer">
                  <a href="#!">Go to detailed information.</a>
                </footer>
              </div>
              <div className="countries__card card">
                <div className="card__flag">
                  <LazyLoad
                    height={windowWidth >= 614 ? "210px" : '173px"'}
                    once
                  >
                    <img
                      width={windowWidth >= 614 ? "320px" : "100%"}
                      height={windowWidth >= 614 ? "210px" : '100%"'}
                      src="https://restcountries.eu/data/blr.svg"
                      alt="flag"
                    />
                  </LazyLoad>
                </div>
                <div className="card__body">
                  <div className="card__body-name">
                    <h5>Lorem</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card__body-infos">
                    <span className="country-capital">Capital: Lorem</span>
                    <span className="country-currencies">Currency: Lorem</span>
                    <span className="country-region">Region: Lorem</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <footer className="card__footer">
                  <a href="#!">Go to detailed information.</a>
                </footer>
              </div>
```

```
.card {
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: rem(50px);
    width: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: showCard 0.7s ease-out forwards;

    img {
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-top-left-radius: 8px;
        border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    }

    &__body,
    &__footer {
        background: $skyblue;
    }

    &__body {
        &-name {
            color: $text-navy;
            padding: rem(10px) 0;
            font-size: rem(20px);
            font-weight: $font-bold;
            font-weight: normal;
            border-bottom: 4px solid $text-navy;
        }

        &-infos {
            padding: rem(15px) 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            color: $text-navy;


            span {
                white-space: nowrap;
                font-size: rem(14.3px);
            }

            span:not(:last-child) {
                padding-right: rem(5px);
                border-right: 3px solid $text-navy;
            }

            span:not(:first-child) {
                padding-left: rem(5px);
            }
        }
    }

    &__footer {
        border-top: 3px solid $text-navy;
        padding: rem(15px) 0;
        background: $text-navy;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Flags have different shapes. If you make the middle one taller, it either has to be wider, or be squashed out of shape.  You need to specify what you want to happen.  It sounds like you want the squash (?)

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard for flag **dimensions**. RestCountries provides flags in their **true** dimensions.

I created a **29 kB Single File** Web Component that does **all** SVG flags in **fixed dimensions** (like most SVG flag Repos do).
And can use RestCountries (or any other SVG flag Repo) as alternative source:

**https://flagmeister.github.io/**

**Alas**, I did not create **all** crests, you picked the exact two I failed to complete: Afghanistan and Andorra for your screenshots. Those flags FlagMeister will default to RestCountries unless prevented with the `detail` setting.

[image]

```html
 <script src="https://flagmeister.github.io/elements.flagmeister.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  div {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(6,100px);
    gap:10px;
  }
  [nodetail] {
    --flagmeisterdetail:99999;
  }
 </style>
  <h3>RestCountries & FlagMeister (forced to no-detail)</h3> 
 <div>
  <flag-af></flag-af>
  <flag-af nodetail></flag-af>
  <flag-by></flag-by>
  <flag-by nodetail></flag-by>
  <flag-ad></flag-ad>
  <flag-ad nodetail></flag-ad>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Danny but in this case, I'll encounter a problem. How can I determine the dynamic component name?

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with making local copies of all the flags.  Then, if you add the following attribute to all SVGs, they will stretch to fit your `<img>` `width` and `height`.

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

For instance, the Belarus flag becomes:

```css
svg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="900" height="450" viewBox="0 0 1098 549" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<title>Flag of Belarus</title>
<rect fill="#C8313E" width="1098" height="549"/>
<rect y="366" fill="#4AA657" width="1098" height="183"/>
<rect fill="#FFF" width="122" height="549"/>
<g id="h">
<g id="q" fill="#C8313E" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="scale(5.304347826,9)">
<path d="M4,0h3v1h1v1h1v1h1v1h1v1h-1v1h-1v1h-1v1h-1v1h-1v1h-1v-1h-1v-1h-1v-1h-1v-1h-1v-1h-1v-1h1v-1h1v-1h1v-1h1zM5,2h1v1h1v1h1v1h-1v1h-1v1h-1v-1h-1v-1h-1v-1h1v-1h1zM5,4h1v1h-1zM0,1h1v1h-1zM0,7h1v1h-1zM11,0h0.6v2h-.6zM11,7h.6v2h-.6zM2,9h1v1h1v1h1v1h-1v1h-1v1h-1v-1h-1v-1h-1v-1h1v-1h1zM2,11h1v1h-1zM8,9h1v1h1v1h1v1h-1v1h-1v1h-1v-1h-1v-1h-1v-1h1v-1h1zM8,11h1v1h-1zM0,15h1v1h-1zM11,14h.6v2h-.6z"/>
<path d="M0,18h1v-1h1v-1h1v-1h1v-1h1v-1h1v1h1v1h1v1h1v1h1v1h1v1h.6v4h-.6v1h-1v1h-1v1h-1v1h-1v1h-1v2.6h-2v-0.6h-1v-1h-1v-1h-1v-1h-1 v-3h1v1h1v1h1v1h1v-1h1v-1h1v-1h1v-1h1v-1h1v-1h-1v-1h-1v-1h-3v1h2v1h-1v1h-1v1h-1v-1h-1v-1h-1v-1h-1zM0,22h1v1h-1zM11,25h.6v1h-.6zM9,27h1v1h1v1h.6v1.6h-.6v-.6h-1v-1h-1zM7,30h1v.6h-1z"/>
</g>
<use xlink:href="#q" transform="translate(122,0) scale(-1,1)"/>
</g>
<use xlink:href="#h" transform="translate(0,549) scale(1,-1)"/>
</svg>
```